# How to change Cartalyst Sentry 2 cookie name?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Cartalyst Sentry 2 in a Laravel 4 application, and one thing I'd like to change is the cookie name for the "remember me" feature, which is "cartalyst_sentry" by default.

I looked at the source code and couldn't figure out a way to change it "cleanly", and I really don't want to change it directly in their source code.

How can I change the "remember me" cookie name without touching Sentry's source code?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Line 32 in /vendor/cartalyst/sentry/src/Cartalyst/Sentry/Cookie/IlluminateCookie.php

```
protected $key = 'cartalyst_sentry';
```

Unfortunately the cookie name is not in the configuration. Otherwise we could just run the following:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

and give our cookie a unique name.

EDIT: See new [issue in Github](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/204)

Comment: Yeah I found that line and was trying to figure out a way to inject a value from outside, but also came up with nothing.

Thanks for opening the issue on GitHub, I'll accept your answer for that reason.

Thanks !

Comment: Ended up doing the pull request myself, the new feature has been merged into the master branch by the cartalyst devs.